# Fixing & Unfixing Element When Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `.SideNav` to navigate my website and `.Main` which is the content of the page. `.SideNav` is an accordian, therefore it is possible for this to be expanded to a height greater than the `.Main` content and visa-versa.

What I am trying to achieve is that when you are scrolling on the page;

**IF** `.SideNav < $(document).height()` - `.SideNav` is fixed and `.Main` can be scrolled as normal.
**IF** `.SideNav < $(document).height()` - `.SideNav` will become fixed when you scroll to and therefore greater than `$(document).height()` whilst `.Main` scrolling normally. When you start scrolling back up however, `.SideNav` will be able to be scrolled to the top position and become fixed again when the top is visible.

Combine **all** methods of page scrolling along with cross-browser compatibility;

- **Scroll Bar**
- **Keyboard**

  - Up/Down keys
  - Page Up/Down Keys
- **Mouse**

  - Mousewheel
  - Mousewheel *- Click and drag*

I've been browsing multiple questions and answers on StackOverflow which have been someone resourceful such as my current scroll direction detection, however this does not work when you click the mouse wheel and I have been unable to resolve my main problem.

My code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"; //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x
    $(document).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){

        var evt = window.event || e; //equalize event object
            evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt; //convert to originalEvent if possible               
        var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta; //check for detail first, because it is used by Opera and FF
        var wh = $(window).height();
        var spt = $(document).scrollTop();
        var spb = $(document).scrollTop() + wh;
        var mainDiv = $('.Main').height() + $('.Main').offset().top;

        if(delta > 0) {
            console.log('Up');
        }
        else{
            if(mainDiv <= spb) {
                console.log('mainDIV: ' + mainDiv + ' spb: ' + spb);
                var te = '-' + (mainDiv - wh) + 'px';
                $('.Main').css({
                    'position'  : 'fixed',
                    'top' : te
                });
            }
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim, if you're using jQuery already I'd think the best option would be to implement the [jQuery scroll method](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/). They deal with cross-browser and different scroll options already. Within the scroll method you could call a function you define to deal with the heights of the elements and scroll position of the user with [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). Here's an example of some work I've done with only one side that might be shorter than the other (the extra numbers that are added are to account for padding and stopping at the right moment):

```
    var scrollPosSetup = function(){

        var mainHeaderHeight     = $('.hero').outerHeight() + 100;
        var footerHeight         = $('footer').outerHeight() + $('.logo-bar').outerHeight() + 240;
        var footerScrollPos      = $('html').height() - (footerHeight + sidebarWrapperHeight);
        var rightSide = (window.innerWidth < 961) ? '30px' : '10%';

        if (window.innerWidth > 767) {

            if($(document).scrollTop() > mainHeaderHeight &&
                $(document).scrollTop() < footerScrollPos) {
                $contactContainer.css({
                    'position' : 'fixed',
                    'top' : '0px',
                    'right' : rightSide
                });
            } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= footerScrollPos ) {
                $contactContainer.css({
                    'position' : 'relative',
                    'top' : footerScrollPos - 500,
                    'right' : ''
                });
            } else {
                $contactContainer.css({
                    'position' : 'relative',
                    'top' : '',
                    'right' : '',
                    'bottom' : ''
                });
            }
        }
    };

    $(window).scroll(function ( e ) {
        scrollPosSetup();
    });
```